# What is the difference between a symlink and binding with fstab?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automounting, fstab, xfs

In Eric Hammond's article [Running MySQL on Amazon EC2 with EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663) he shows how to add a second drive (`/vol/`) and then progresses to move `mysql`'s config and data there.

`/sdh` gets mounted as `/vol` by editing `fstab` and adding:

```
/dev/sdh /vol xfs noatime 0 0
```

And next some paths are added like this:

```
/vol/etc/mysql /etc/mysql     none bind
```

I don't have a problem with doing this way but I don't quite understand what is going on.

I can most closely compare this to using a symlink, something like:

```
ln -s /etc/mysql /vol/etc/mysql
```

I've taken a look at `man fstab` without seeing much information about the `bind` syntax and can't find it in the `fstab` section in the Linux Administrator's Handbook either. Can someone shed some light on `fstab`'s `bind` syntax, how it works, what it does, and where I should be able to find more information on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bind` mirrors a filesystem (among other situatons, it's useful when setting a chroot inside which you need to have a "complete" system (like when unpacking/installing Gentoo).

Just simply like that, it mirrors a tree from A into B. I don't know for sure if it has any option, but I doubt it, it does not do more than, well, mirroring.

Unlike a symlink, which is a file in a filesystem pointing to another filesystem, requiring you to set it up, and is still a "special file", bind really mirrors the whole subtree. Depending on the tool, both strategies may work, but it is possible to detect the symlink and some tools may resolve it to the original path. The `bind` approach is more transparent, acting like two different filesystems.

Comment: Just had to do this last night, excellent answer. this is the description from LFS build docs: ....since this is a new system and does not have Udev and has not yet been booted, it is necessary to mount and populate `/dev` manually. This is accomplished by `bind`mounting the host system's `/dev` directory. A bind mount is a special type of mount that allows you to create a mirror of a directory or mount point to some other location..

Comment: Exactly. Symlinks that reference inodes outside of a chroot environment won't work. You can link `/mychroot/home` to `/home` before you `chroot(2)`, but *after* you chroot, the symlink is broken (`/mychroot` no longer exists from the point of view of the chrooted environment). Binding to the rescue.

Comment: You can have a read only bind mount, but symlinks can't change the permissions of the target.

Comment: When you say "mirror" I panicked thinking it was going to copy all the files, it acts more like a directory hard-link, the two directories are simply the same directory, something that happens in one happens in the other, because they are the same event.